# changing the value of a global variable in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm prototyping an app and want to have a global variable that I can hit an endpoint that toggles the global variable $current_status. I have:

```
  def toggle_status
     $current_status=false if $current_status.nil?
     $current_status=!$current_status
     r={}
     r[:current_status]=$current_status
     render json:r.to_json
  end
```

and in application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  $current_status
end
```

but hitting /toggle_status always returns false. Why isn't assigning a bool to what it isn't changing this value? I'm aware something like this should be in db but just prototyping

#### edit 1

I just created this in lib/

```
class Jt
  @cur
  def self.cur
    @cur
  end

  def self.cur=val
    @cur=val
  end
end
```

and updated the controller to:

```
  def toggle_status
     Jt.cur=!Jt.cur
     r={}
     r[:current_status]=Jt.cur
     render json:r.to_json
  end
```

Comment: Hi, sorry I'm not quite clear what your trying to do.. Is it toggle from false to true or false to nil? (Nil being equal to false in rails).

Comment: hitting this endpoint will toggle to what it is not (not sure if nil goes to true) and globally accessible to app. it's a prototype so don't want other pieces right now

Comment: No worries, then I think your issue with the logic here lies with foo != foo ,that's a comparison. Try instead foo = !foo

Comment: doh, thx @Eoghain - I ended up just creating a static variable on a class in lib and seems to work fine (in edit 1)

Answer (score 1):

Your toggle code doesn't actually toggle anything. It appears you expect this line to "toggle" the contents of the `$current_status` variable.

```
$current_status!=$current_status
```

However, the `!=` operator doesn't assign anything but it is a comparison operator. In your case, it returns always `false` based on your query whether `$current_status` is equal to `not $current_status`.

What you want to use instead is probably

```
$current_status = !$current_status
```

As for your software design, global variables are generally frowned upon in Ruby (and Rails) as are all other kinds of globally mutable state. Use proper classes and objects instead to encapsulate your state and behaviour into more manageable structures. Using global variables, you *will* shoot yourself in the foot some day and you will have a very hard time to find out what is actually happening. You should try to avoid this :)

Comment: i've updated the first part - just a typo on my part. The odd thing is that $current_status isn't a global variable in any traditional sense and can't be written to (as in a variable). As a prototype, design is secondary.

Comment: Ruby has real global variables, and `$current_status` is one of those. There exists only one value and it is accessible from anywhere in your process.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a global variable in this way in such app and there are several reasons. I'll give you just one: depending on the webserver you use, the server may start different processes to handle the incoming web requests, and global variables can't be shared between these processes.

And in fact, it's not even a good idea to use a global variable at all.

If you want to persist a state, use a proper storage. Depending on how long the value should be persisted and who should be able to access it, you have plenty of choices:

- database
- file system
- memory
- cookie

Comment: agreed this isn't how I would this in production but just curious in this prototype and on webrick to single process. Really no way to do it this way as a global variable (btw, it's atrocious in the Rails community how they refer to a global constant as a a global variable)

Answer (score 0):

Your first snipper does not work because `!=` is a comparison operator, not assignment

Second may not work due to code reloading (`Jt` class instance is not guaranteed to be the same for other request unless `cache_classes` is on, but in development you usually always want it off, because otherwise any code changes require server restart to take effect), simple way to have a non-reloaded class - put it in a initializer

For prototyping you also may try thread-local storage for this task: `Thread.current[:foo] = 1234`